# How to increase the default timeout of a function in Apify

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer, apify

I'm currently using the web-**scraper** actor of Apify
I'm trying to **scrape** a page which is quite long to load. I already faced this kind of situation and using the code underneath always worked.

```
async function pageFunction(context) {...
await context.waitFor(...);
...}
```

however this time the page is really slow to load and it reach the function `[await context.waitFor(...)]` timeout of 20 seconds. Is there a way to increase this duration above the default one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the second parameter `options`, where you can set a timeout.

```
async function pageFunction(context) {
  await context.waitFor('selector', { timeoutMillis: 60000 });
}
```

I have to search this parameter in [GitHub repo of web-scraper](https://github.com/apifytech/actor-scraper). I will create an issue for document this in the readme.

Comment: There is an issue you can subscribe to it if you want to https://github.com/apifytech/actor-scraper/issues/29